# No parameterless constructor defined for this object, automapper 8 and IValueResolver

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, automapper-8

I use AutoMapper 8 in a project and I want to make use of a resolver as shown below. The problem I got this message error:

> MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this
>   object.

and I don't know if I missing something here.

```
public class ExcelClientProfile : Profile
    {
        public ExcelClientProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Ticket, ExcelClient>()
                ...
                .ForMember(d => d.FormModel, s => s.MapFrom<FormBuilderWithAnswerResolver>());
        }
    }

    public class FormBuilderWithAnswerResolver : IValueResolver<Ticket, ExcelClient, FormModel>
    {
        private IFormBuilderService _formBuilderService;

        public FormBuilderWithAnswerResolver(IFormBuilderService formBuilderService)
        {
            _formBuilderService = formBuilderService;
        }

        public FormModel Resolve(Ticket source, ExcelClient destination, FormModel destMember, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            return _formBuilderService.GetFormBuilderWithAnswersExcel(source);
        }
    }
```

Do you know how can I make this work?

Thank you,

David

---

Stacktrace

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this
>   object. System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, bool
>   publicOnly,  bool wrapExceptions, ref bool canBeCached, ref
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal ctor)
>
> AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types: Ticket -> ExcelClient Core.Models.Ticket ->
>   Service.Models.TicketOrderView.ExcelClient
>
> Type Map configuration: Ticket -> ExcelClient Core.Models.Ticket ->
>   Service.Models.TicketOrderView.ExcelClient
>
> Destination Member: FormModel lambda_method(Closure ,
>   IQueryable , ICollection , ResolutionContext )
>
> AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types: IQueryable`1 -> ICollection`1
>   System.Linq.IQueryable`1[[Core.Models.Ticket, Core, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] ->
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[Service.Models.TicketOrderView.ExcelClient,
>   Service, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

And also:

```
    public class Ticket : Entity
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            ...
            public virtual FormBuilder FormBuilder { get; set; }
            public Ticket()
            {

            }

            public object Clone()
            {
                return this.MemberwiseClone();
            }
        }

        public class ExcelClient
        {
            ...
public virtual FormModel FormModel { get; set; }
            public ExcelClient()
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: what are the information needed? Ticket and ExcelClient are just class with properties.

Comment: Please can you provide the class definitions for `Ticket`, and `ExcelClient`, and the full stack trace.

Comment: It is always good idea to re-read [MCVE] guidance from time to time ...

Comment: I added full stack trace with Ticket and ExcelClient classes.

Comment: Can you show how you're creating your Mapper instance?

Comment: in the startup class ConfigureServices method I added services.AddAutoMapper(); services.AddScoped<IMapper, Mapper>();

Comment: Hmm, if you remove `services.AddScoped<IMapper, Mapper>();` does it make a difference? `.AddAutoMapper` registers `IMapper`.

Comment: maybe, the error has change: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. give me some minutes :)

Comment: It works :) Thanks John !!!